# Where should I place my users method in Symfony 4?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-4.2

I followed the symfony 4 documentation to make a login form (https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html) and I added a registration form in the same controller.

I'm a beginner, and I would like to make an account page where the user will be able to change his informations, but I would like to know if I should create a new Controller who work with the user entity, on just work onthe same controller than the login and registration ? 
Or maybe my user controller have to inherit the securityController?

I'm a noob, sorry ^^'

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can give a look at https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#creating-configuring-services-in-the-container

The path is creating your own service(s), for example `App\Servie\UserManager` that performs every task on a User object

For example, you could have:

```
App\Service\UserManager

class UserManager
{
    // ...
    public function handleUpdatePasswordRequest(Request $request) {...}

    // or
    public function handleUpdatePasswordForm(Form $form) {...}

    // or:
    public function handleUpdatePassword(User $user, $newPlainPassword) {...}

    ...
}
```

as to say, whatever you want to implement, keeping in mind that the thinner the controllers are better it is, while services can grow (and be split) indefinitely

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help.
I made a Service namespace where I put my UserManager. So If I understand, I have to "use" this controller in my security controller where I have my account route ?

Comment: you can add a pastebin here, anyway you can do something like https://pastebin.com/sz1SAJzm

Comment: It's ok, I understood, I made an accountController with my account's methods.
Thank for your help

Comment: correct . if you found that useful, consider voting up mu answer :) cheers!